# How to print leading spaces before char array in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

char a[30];
char b[30];
scanf("%[^\n]s",a);
scanf(" %[^\n]s",b);
printf("%s \n",a);
printf("%s",b);
return 0;
}
```

Input :

```
    hai
        hello
```

Output :

```
    hai
hello
```

But I am expecting

```
    hai
        hello
```

How to print leading spaces before hello?

Comment: Skip the white space in scanning format string and get rid of the newlines otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @Yunnosch
But if I skip the white space in second scanf , It is not printing the second input (hello).

Comment: That is because you need to get rid of the newlines blocking your attempt to  read a non-newline. It is still lingering in input and has until now been eaten by the leading white space in the second scan format, along with the white space you want to keep. Try reading it explicitly and ignoring it.

Comment: Could you give an example? @Yunnosch

Comment: The absolute *best* advise anyone can give here is to use `fgets` for user input and trim the trailing `'\n'`, *avoid* `scanf` as it has a number of pitfall for new C programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char a[30];
  char b[30];
  fgets(a, 30, stdin);
  fgets(b, 30, stdin);
  printf("%s \n",a);
  printf("%s",b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the first printf statement printing newline even if  I remove  **'\n'** ?

Comment: @CHANDRUTK14BCS023 this is because when you get a whole line via `fgets`, you also get the newline charactor `\n`. This is one thing you need to be careful about when you are using different input functions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `%[…]` (a scan set) is a complete conversion specification.  The `s` after it in your code never matches anything, but you can't spot that.  The newline is left in the input.  You'd have to arrange to read that before using the second scan set — and a space (or newline) in the format string is not the answer to that.  Replacing the `s` with `%*c` would do the job.  But you're probably best off not using `scanf()` at this point; use `fgets()` instead.

#### Using `scanf()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[30];
    char b[30];
    if (scanf("%29[^\n]%*c", a) == 1 &&
        scanf("%29[^\n]%*c", b) == 1)
    {
        printf("[%s]\n", a);
        printf("[%s]\n", b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
    hai
        hello
```

Output:

```
[    hai]
[        hello]
```

#### Using `fgets()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[30];
    char b[30];
    if (fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin) != 0 &&
        fgets(b, sizeof(b), stdin) != 0)
    {
        a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = '\0';
        b[strcspn(b, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("[%s]\n", a);
        printf("[%s]\n", b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For the same input, this produces the same output.